# React : How do you write id to have dynamic axios requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, undefined

I'm new to React, and despite many attempts I can't figure out how to set my id dynamically in axios requests in my edit-form.

I tried to set the axios requests with a static number just to test my edit-form, I can log my object but when I submit it deletes the product data instead of updating with the new data because the id is undefined.

I think I just need to find out what to write in my componentDidMount and handleSubmit to catch the id.
For example ${this.state.product.id} is undefined, why isn't it working?

It's my first question, so I hope I am clear and tell me if you need more code.

EditForm

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import axios from 'axios';

import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import FormControl from 'react-bootstrap/FormControl';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

class EditForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { product: [] };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    };
    
    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios
        .get(`/products/edit-form/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.products);
            this.setState({
                product: response.data.products
            })
        });
    
    };

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({id: e.target.value})
        this.setState({reference: e.target.value})
        this.setState({designation: e.target.value})        
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();     
        const data = { 
        id: this.state.product.id,
        reference: this.state.product.reference,
        designation: this.state.product.designation        
        };

        axios
        .post(`/products/${this.props.match.params.id}`, data )
        .then(res => console.log(res))      
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    };
 
    renderForm() {
        return this.state.product.map((product, index) => {
            const { id,reference,designation } = product
        return(
            <>         
            <Form className="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <Form.Row>
                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridReference">
                    <Form.Label>Reference</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.product.reference} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} name="reference" placeholder={reference} />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridDesignation">
                    <Form.Label>Designation</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" value={this.state.product.designation} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} name="designation" placeholder={designation} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Form.Row>                

                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Submit
                </Button>
            </Form>
            </>
            );
        })
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Formulaire de modification</h1>
                {this.renderForm()}
            </div>        
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(EditForm);
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <NavBar />            
                <Router>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Products}/>
                    <Route path="/edit-form/:productId" component={EditForm}/>
                </Router>
            </React.Fragment>  

        );
    }
}
```

Products

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const headings = [
    'id','reference','designation'
];

export default class Products extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            products: []
        };
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get("/products").then(response => {
            console.log(response.data.products);
            this.setState({
                products: response.data.products
            })
        });
    };
 
    renderTableHeader() {       
        return headings.map((key, index) => {
        return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>
        })
    } 

    renderProductData() {
        return this.state.products.map((product, index) => {
            const { id,reference,designation } = product
            return (
                <tr key={id}>
                    <td>
                        {id}
                        <Link to={`/edit-form/${id}`}>Modifier</Link>
                    </td>
                    <td>{reference}</td>
                    <td>{designation}</td>                               
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
 
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 id='title'>Produits</h1>
                <Table striped bordered hover id='products'>
                    <thead>
                        {this.renderTableHeader()}
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.renderProductData()}
                    </tbody>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Async functions

```
// productController.js

const getProduct = async (req, res) => 
{
    const { productId } = req.params;
    const product = await productDb.getProduct(productId);
    res.status(200).send({ products: product.rows });    
};

const postProduct = async (req, res) => 
{
    const { productId } = req.params;
    const { reference,designation } = req.body;
    await productDb.updateProduct(productId, reference, designation);
    res.status(200).send(`Le produit reference ${reference} a été modifié`);  
    console.log(`Le produit reference ${reference} a été modifié`); 


// productDb.js

const getProduct = async (id) =>
{
    const connection = new DbConnection();
    return await connection.performQuery(`SELECT * FROM produits WHERE id=${id}`);
};

const updateProduct = async (id, reference, designation) =>
{
    const connection = new DbConnection();
    await connection.performQuery("UPDATE produits SET reference=?, designation=? WHERE id=?", 
    [reference, designation, id]);
};
```

Thank you

Comment: It looks like you are using `id: this.state.id,` instead of `id: this.state.product.id,` in the `HandleSubmit` method of `EditForm` component or am I wrong?

Comment: Why are you changing the all of the edit form state in each handleChange? also you should use the id from the product state `ths.state.product.id`, not `this.state.id`

Comment: Yes, I forgot the product you're right. But even by adding it and writing `.post(`/products/${this.state.product.id}`, data )`
I still have my undefined problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Products.js`, you are using links to open up your `EditForm` component. So, for you to be able to access the `product id`, you need to wrap your `EditForm` component with the `withRouter hoc` from the `react-router` library. This hoc will then make the `match` prop available to your `EditForm` component.

So, you need to add `react-router` to your dependencies by running this:

```
yarn add react-router **OR** npm install react-router
```

Then add it to your import statements in `EditForm.js`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
```

And then inside `componentDidMount`, you should be able to access the `id` by doing this:

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

You also need to change your class definition to:

```
class EditForm extends React.Component
```

And then export it like this:

```
export default withRouter(EditForm)
```

I assume in your `routes` file, you must have a route that is defined like this:

```
<Route path="/edit-form/:id" component={EditForm} />
```

Comment: Yes my route is like this as you can see. I updated with your advices, but `this.state.product` and `id` are still undefined. Should I use props everywhere ?

Comment: Change your route definition from `<Route path="/edit-form/:productId" component={EditForm}/>` to `<Route path="/edit-form/:id" component={EditForm}/>`. You are trying to access `this.props.match.params.id`.